# Difficulty combining these SQL queries into 1 query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to be able to run the following queries together, but I don't know how to do so without getting errors.

I would like to combine this...

```
UPDATE table1
   SET facebookurl = ( SELECT facebookurl
                   FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname )
```

...with this...

```
UPDATE table1
   SET email = ( SELECT email 
                   FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname )
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname )
```

...and eventually 3 or 4 more with the exact same structure (with only the source and destination columns being changed).

Is there a simple way to combine these while avoiding errors?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "combine" them? And which database are you using? MySQL and Oracle are not the same. Please remove the tag that does not belong.

Comment: Use semicolon in the end of each query. `...WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname ); # <-- SEMICOLON`

Comment: @PatrickQ - I'm not sure how to tell which one I am using. My guess would be MySQL. I'm using phpMyAdmin, but I don't know if that helps answer your question. What's the best way for me to determine if I'm using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL

```
UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN socialmedia s
       ON  s.fullname = a.fullname
   SET a.email = s.email, a.facebookurl  = s.facebookurl;
```

Oracle

```
UPDATE table1
   SET (email, facebookurl) = 
                  (SELECT email, facebookurl
                   FROM socialmedia
                  WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM socialmedia
              WHERE socialmedia.fullname = table1.fullname);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the Oracle version, but got an error. I want to try the MySQL version, but I don't know what the 'a' and 's' are or represent. I'm very new to SQL. Are these example representations or something else? Thank you.

Comment: @point71echo if you're working in Oracle and got an error then maybe your subquery returns more than one row (for some table1.fullname). Is it a case?

Comment: Here is the full code I used and the resulting error... `UPDATE testtable
SET title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname = (SELECT title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname
               FROM socialmedia
             WHERE socialmedia.fullname = testtable.fullname)`  "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname = (SELECT title, email, twitterurl, f' at line 2"

Comment: @point71echo Try this: UPDATE testtable SET (title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname) = ... Parentheses are mandatory when you set several columns!

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know if I'm using MySQL or Oracle. I thought they were the same before I posted this question. Is there a simple way to determine which one I'm using?

Comment: I got the same error... "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname) = (SELECT title, email, twitt' at line 2"

Comment: @point71echo Use the first update from my answer in MySQL. You're trying to run the second update which will work only in Oracle

Comment: Good eye. Thank you. Can you help me adapt the MySQL version of your code to `UPDATE testtable
SET (title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname) = (SELECT title, email, twitterurl, facebookurl, classname
               FROM socialmedia
             WHERE socialmedia.fullname = testtable.fullname)` ?

Comment: @point71echo 'a' and 's' are short names of your tables. With them you resolve conflicts when address columns from different tables having the same column names

Comment: @point71echo UPDATE testtable a INNER JOIN socialmedia s ON s.fullname = a.fullname SET a.title = s.title, a.email = s.email, a.twitterurl = s.twitterurl, a.facebookurl = facebookurl, a.classname = s.classname;

Comment: The last code you provided worked perfectly. Thank you for all of your help.